# How to Configure Flat Rate Shipping Method in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

i need help with magento 2.

i am developing a module in magento 2.2.2.
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/shipping/shipping-flat-rate.html
in my module i need modify values of shipping-flat-rate.
eg: title, price.
how get and update values of shipping-flat-rate since my module?.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> project_magento/app/code/Dev/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Filter/Edit/Tab/Info.php

```
namespace Proveedor\Gnuxdar\Block\Adminhtml\Filter\Edit\Tab;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
...
class Info extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    protected $_scopeConfigInterface;

...
    public function __construct(
        ...
        )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
        $this->_scopeConfigInterface = $scopeConfigInterface;
        $this->_countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollectionFactory;
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $path = 'carriers/flatrate/';
        $country = $this->_scopeConfigInterface->getValue($path.'specificcountry', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface:Smiley FrustratedCOPE_STORE);

        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(['data'=>['id'=>'edit_form', 'action'=>$this->....

        $fieldset->addField(
            'enabled',
            'select',
            [
                'name'=>'enabled',
                'label'=>__('Enabled'),
                'required'=>true,
                'values'=>array(0=>'No', 1=>'Yes'),
                'value'=>$this->_scopeConfigInterface->getValue($path.'active', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface:Smiley FrustratedCOPE_STORE)
            ]
        );
```